# Windows Store reject the submitted app

Tags: windows-store-apps

We have submitted our app today over Windows Store.

Now, We found one change, so is there anyway to reject previous build and submit the new build? It is submitted today morning only, so it may not be in testing cycle. So, We want to apply this change if possible.

Do we have to wait for app submission status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the Dev Center portal, you can resubmit your application while the previous one is still being reviewed. You can as well view the current review status of your app in the portal

The certification process starts again at the beginning though.

You can manage your app submissions here : https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-US/Home/Index